# Get value checkbox in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In Vue:

```
<b-form-checkbox
   checked="true"
   name="check-status"
   switch
   inline
   @change="chageStatus"
>
</b-form-checkbox>

data {
  return: {
    status:'',
  }
}
methods: {
  changeStatus() {
    // I want to get the value status here
 }
}
```

My problem is if i set `v-model="status"` i get the result when i change status. But when I set the `v-model` my `checked="true"` value doesn't work, when the page loads it passes false? Please help me

Comment: try ```status: true,```and```v-model="status"```

Answer (score 0):

Try out to get the checkbox value from the event handler parameter:

```
methods: {
  changeStatus(val) {
   this.status=val
 }
}
```